# Generating Sample Data in Expression Blend

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

I am looking for a good practice in this scenario: I am working with Expression Blend, and want to create a datatemplate for the items in a listbox. I already have project with a model class, lets call it User which will be the holder of data to be displayed in the ListBox items. And what I want to do is to get some sample data containing users that can be bound to the listbox to view the design work in progress.

Microsofts idea with Blend is for it to rid the need of programming skills for designer folks in the process of creating the UI. So I was expecting there to be a way to generate a sample data based on the pre existing code, in this case User class, without any coding.

The proposed solutions that can be done from Blend that I've seen are either, generate an xml-file with elements of type User, and then create a sample data source out of this and bind it to the ListBox. Or, select "new sample data" in the Data tab which will create a collection of a new type with a set of properties that can be managed from Blend. None of theses options are what I am looking for, the first since it will demand the user to precreate an xml file, which is not part of a designers job, the second doesn't meet the requirement of being a data source containing the relevant type, User.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stub data for designers when using Expression Blend and Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486/how-do-i-stub-data-for-designers-when-using-expression-blend-and-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

On the Data tab, "Create Sample Data" button, there is an option for "Create Sample Data from Class". As long as the class is already defined and referenced in the project, I think this will do what you want.

Comment: As far as I can see this creates a single object data sample. Or is there a way to create a collection of objects of the class that can be used to populate the ListBox?

Comment: I hadn't tried it in years, but I went and tested it and you are correct. I next tried to put a collection of the target type in a ViewModel class and generate that, but it didn't even generate the list property. This is far from optimal in VS12, I'm a little surprised (and a lot disappointed) to be honest.

Comment: The only other recommendation I would make is to use the "New Sample Data" feature and just be sure to name the sample properties the *exact* same as the actual classes.  That way, down the road you can just swap out the data source.